# Failure to save thumbnail image into BLOB MySQL after getting it transformed

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I get image by URL, need to fit and resize to thumbnail and store it in BLOB MySql for further access of multiple users (suggestion not to store image in BLOB is not suiting here). I do transformation using GD class.

The problem is when I try to save it in BLOB column, I get this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Вў|Г¶ВіВџ}Г¦В™gВѕГёГ…/~Г«[ГџВ‡ГћГ»*ВЌ1ГћГ»)IFГ±aIhВґГ„4В­(Г…В«jВїГџГЇГ·Г»' at line 1`

```
    $im = fill_image_png($link) ;  // GD library work 
       // get the image into the buffer from the image identifier   
    ob_start();
    imagepng($im);
    $stringdata = ob_get_contents(); // read from buffer
    ob_end_clean(); // delete buffer
    $zdata = gzdeflate($stringdata);
    $zdata = mb_convert_encoding ($zdata, "utf-8");
       //store into mysql db
    if (insert_image($_db, $table_name, $item['link'],  $zdata ) ) { echo "<em><strong>Image is stored into DB</em></strong><br/>"; }
    else  { echo "Failed to store image as binary<br/>"; }
```

The code for the stored procedure is:

```
function insert_image($db_handler, $table_name, $link, $image) {
mysqli_query($db_handler,"UPDATE {$table_name} SET Thumbnail = '{$image}' WHERE Link = '{$link}' " );
}
```

`Thumbnail' column is of a`MEDIUMBLOB` type.

What's wrong/missing?

Comment: You're missing proper way of storing images - in a filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

i was given a right answer to use mysqli_stmt for passing parameters into sql query. This works both for avoiding injections like `'; delete from {$tablename};` and also leaves no need for `'` escape:

```
    function insert_image($db_handler, $table_name, $link, $image) {
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_handler, "UPDATE {$table_name} SET Thumbnail = ? WHERE Link = '{$link}' " );
     mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $image);// whether 's' or 'b' - no avail

// execute prepared statement 
     if ( !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) ) 
    {  echo "Error inserting image into <em><strong>{$table_name}</strong></em>: " . mysqli_error($db_handler) ;
        echo "<br/>";
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        return False; 
    }
     mysqli_stmt_close($stmt); // close the stmt
        return True;
}
```

Now there is no SQL error appear, yet the **blob field remains untouched** (i check with PHPMyAdmin). The data in the `$image` variable is not that big, able to fit in BLOB. What's wrong?